# Programmatically Click 'Download All' button on Web Page in C#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, web

Good Day Folks,

I am trying to automate a bit of C# code which will click on the Download All button on a website (JotForm). We initially attempted using the JotForm API to export form/table data to a text file however their API solution doesn't seem to be playing ball and JotForm Support simply aren't answering the questions we have. The JotForm form/table we created is shown below and the screenshot I have taken shows the HTML code when I right click the Download All button and select Inspect;

[image]

We are therefore looking at automating the download of the data as a CSV. So far in C# I have the following code;

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
            //webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate("https://soas.jotform.com/212224049348048");
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://soas.jotform.com/212224049348048");

            
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "https://soas.jotform.com/212224049348048";

            foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
                {
                   if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "txt" && el.InnerText.Contains("Download All") )
                   {
                    el.InvokeMember("click");
                    }
                }

        }
```

The Download All button can of course be clicked with manual human intervention, but we would like to have a bit of code do this for us instead. Now, when I Debug and click Button2 in my VS Form to try and programmatically call the Download All button on the web page, I get a Javascript popup detailing a Script Error as shown here;
[image]

Of course this Javascript error is only a fragment of the issue we are trying to resolve - the main issue is how we can achieve clicking the Download All button on the web page from the C# code. I'd be more than grateful if you could point me in the right direction as I am now at a loss.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The `WebBrowser` control is [stuck in IE7 mode](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version) by default. If the site you're accessing doesn't support IE7 - and most don't - then you'll get errors.

If the site supports IE11, then you could try editing the registry on every PC where your code will run to try to make the control use IE11 mode. Rick's blog post has the details - essentially, you need to create a `DWORD` value under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` with the same name as your `.exe`, and set it to `11000` or `11001`.

A more robust solution would be to use a different control which uses a more modern browser engine. Eg: [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) uses the same engine as Chrome. [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) is Microsoft's offering, which uses the Chromium version of Edge.

Alternatively, you could use something like a [Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/introduction) desktop flow to automate the task.

Comment: thank you for the prompt response. Will check out Power Automate. We have downloaded it but have received some errors. Will let you know if these are resolved and if it's a feasible solution for us.